# Blip2 for image metada

Tags: computer-vision

I want to detect attributes of objects in an image - like what is color of a patch on shirt of person, how many patches are there, type of objects, exact dimensions of the objects etc

I've heard of [Blip2](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/main/model_doc/blip-2) but I'm not sure if this will do what I need above. Can someone suggest if Blip2 is right model or some other model is better for such metadata detection?